# JDBC : ResulSet.getObject() gives values with spaces at the end

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve a column value which is of type CHAR(1 Byte) from a table. The value in table is N, but when i use ResuleSet.getObject() to retrieve this value i get N followed by 2 spaces. This behavior is seen only in some environments, say UAT. I did some detailed analysis and found that when we use classes12.jar this issue occurs, but if we use ojdbc14.jar the issue is not there. But i am unable to find an exact reason why this behavior occurs. My applications war file conatins classes12.jar in the WEB-INF lib and jboss lib folder has both these jar files , classes12 and ojdbc. When i give ojdbc14.jar in the endorsed folder in jboss, the issue of spaces is resolved. From this it seems if we have ojdbc14.jar then this issues is resolved.  How can i explain clearly why the difference and is there any way to find out in jboss which is the class loading precedence for the jar files in lib folder, which causes issue in one environment but not in another ?

Comment: classes12 is very old (as is ojdbc14 btw), so it is probably just a bug that got fixed in newer versions of the driver.

Comment: Please show us the table definition. Sounds like the column is defined as `char(3)`. The `char` datatypes is always padded to the defined length. And as Mark already said: both drivers are totally outdated (`classes12.jar` is for Java **1.2** and `ojdbc14.jar` is for Java **1.4** unless you are stuck with an unsupported Java version you should upgrade to a recent driver)

Comment: Thanks both of you. The table definition is as follows :  MY_COLUMN         CHAR(1 BYTE)         DEFAULT 'N'                   NOT NULL,

Comment: Can you please suggest a recent driver that we can use the jdk version is 1.6 so that we need not do any code change. Also do you know why there is a difference in different environments, both of the env is using the same jars.

Comment: I have found an option to identify the jar file being referenced by the oracle driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'. Please see this link to add the properties to jboss-log4j.xml to get class loading information : http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/LinkageErrors___Making_Sure_You_Are_Who_You_Say_You_Are-Debugging_Class_Loading_Issues.html#Debugging_Class_Loading_Issues-An_example_log4j.xml_configuration_fragment_for_enabling_verbose_class_loading_logging